# Google Maps API Coordinates Ranges Calculation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coordinates, geocoding, latitude-longitude, google-geocoder

Following Problem: I have a database table with pins coordinates (lat, lng). I send my maps current bounds to the backend to choose visible pins from the database. My code (cakePHP) is following:

```
private function getMapData($level = 1)
{
    $x1 = $this->request->query('x1');
    $x2 = $this->request->query('x2');
    $y1 = $this->request->query('y1');
    $y2 = $this->request->query('y2');

    if ($x1 > $x2)
    {
        $tmp = $x1;
        $x1 = $x2;
        $x2 = $tmp;
    }
    if ($y1 > $y2)
    {
        $tmp = $y1;
        $y1 = $y2;
        $y2 = $tmp;
    }


    return $this->Map->find('all',
        array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Map.lat',
                'Map.lng',
                'Map.level_number'
            ),
            'conditions' => array('Map.level_number' => $level,
            'Map.lat BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($x1, $x2),
            'Map.lng BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($y1, $y2),
            ),

            'group' => 'Map.lat, Map.lng, Map.level_number' //for distinct values
        ));
}
```

The query just picks the pins with coordinates in bounds' range. It works most of the time and it doesn't matter which bound's corner comes first - left/right/top/bottom.
But sometimes this simple calculation seems not to work.
I'm getting the bounds and the center point. If I apply the calculation on the center point it's sometimes not within tne bounds which is realy strange but it's really correct data. So I suspect there is something else in this bounds calculation I didn't think about.
here is an example of parameters I get: ?x1=68.62149425024305&y1=150.81473437500006&x2=-16.728397127562125&y2=173.31473437500006&x=36.520571863374705&y=-377.93526562499994&z=3
x1 and y1 is corner point 1
x2, y2 corner point 2
x,y is center
z is zoomlevel
this isn't a good example as center's lng = -377,9.. but I've got requests with coordinates within range lat between -90 and 90 and lng between -180 and 180 and still my calculation fails I get zero data from database and center point which I get from maps api is not within the bounds I get from the same api

Comment: How do you calculate centre coordinates.

Comment: I dont calculate them, it's done by the api's function in frontend: this.map.getCenter() I recon

Answer (score -1):

When it's so far off you can add 180° and use absolute value:abs(-377.9+180).

Comment: but what's wrong when it's inside the range [-180;180] it still makes problems

Comment: Maybe add 180. I don't know what's wrong. Maybe a hardware failure?

Comment: no, the coordinates are correct, I just don't understand the coordinate system in this case